# File Name Bubble Hovering on Screen?

Tags: finder, filesystem

I'm not sure what just happened...
I was just about to rename a file, and just mis-clicked off. - After that point there was a constantly floating yellow bubble with the file name in it, on the finder window. I couldn't click it or drag it, however if I showed desktop it would float off screen along with the finder window.

I force closed Finder, and it was gone when I re-opened. Just very intrigued as to what this was? As it didn't seem like a bug (As it tended to float and act in unison with the finder window).

Any ideas?

iMac
OS X 10.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've managed to replicate it myself, seems like a bug.

If you start to edit a filename, right click, click "look up "File name here"", then quickly click off, the yellow look up box will stay floating on the screen.

Screenshot here:
[image: Yellow Bubble Apple Bug Finder]